# Polynomials in an arbitrary field $F$

Tags: field-theory

Let $p(t)$ be a polynomial of degree $n+1$ of an arbitrary field $F$. Suppose that $p(t)$ is a product of linear terms. Let $\lambda$ be one of its roots. So we can represent $p(t)$, up to a multiplicative constant as:

$$p(t) = (t-\lambda)\cdot (t-r_1)\cdot \;\dots \;\cdot(t-r_n)$$

Finally, let $d(t)$ be another polynomial such that:

$$
p(t) = (t-\lambda)d(t)
$$

Is it true that 
$$
d(t) = (t-r_1)\cdot \; \dots \cdot (t-r_n)
$$
?

The subtlety here is that we can't divide by $t-\lambda$ when $t=\lambda$. In the usual case where $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $F = \mathbb{C}$, the field is infinite, so the relation 
$$
d(t) = p(t)(t-\lambda)^{-1} \;\; t\neq\lambda
$$
gives us an infinite number of equations which uniquely determine $d(t)$. So my question here is concerned with the case of a finite field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. In fact, it’s equivalent to the Euclidean algorithm for long division. Let $h(t)$ be that product. Then $p(t) - p(t) = (t-\lambda)(d(t)-h(t))$. Since the degree is additive under product of nonzero polynomials, if $d(t) - h(t)$ is not identically $0$, it has negative degree! So $d(t) \equiv h(t)$.

Also, this holds for any arbitrary field. And we’re good to go.

Answer (score 1):

> The subtlety here is that we can't divide by $t−λ$ when $t=λ$.

That's not relevant. Polynomials are not functions and $t$ isn't equal to anything but $t$. $t$ is an indeterminate, not a variable.

A polynomial is equal to zero if and only if all of its coefficients are zero. This means that $F[t]$ is always an integral domain (in fact a PID). Being a domain, all non-zero elements, such as $t - \lambda$ are non-zero-divisors and the usual rule applies. That is if $ax = ay$ and $a$ is not a zero-divisor then $x = y$. Then $ax = ay$ and hence $d(t) = \prod (t - r_i)$.

If you take $a = t - \lambda$ and $x = d(t)$ and $y = \prod (t - r_i)$

Comment: How are polynomials not functions? One question that might clarify this is the following: suppose we have a finite field $F$ of order $|F|$. There are $|F|^2$ functions from $F$ to itself. Thus, we can find two polynomials of different degrees and coefficients that represent the same function from $F$ to itself (the function representation here is obtained by plugging an element of $F$ in $t$). Do we consider these polynomials different or equal? Rereading your first paragraph, I think you would consider them different?

Comment: @fadi77 "polynomial functions" are functions. Polynomials are not. Two polynomial functions are equal if they agree at every element of $F$. Two polynomials are equal if they have the same coefficients. For example $t^2 + t$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is zero as a function but not as a polynomial. This means that $t$ and $t + 1$ are zero divisors in the ring of polynomial functions. A polynomial gives you a polynomial function on $F$ but also on every extension of $F$. $t^2 + t$ is the zero function on $\mathbb{Z}/2$ but not on any proper extension of it.

Comment: I haven't gotten to rings or integral domains yet. In fact, my question originated after reading section 6 of chapter 5 of Mike Artin's _Algebra_. However, your post made a conceptual shift in the way I think about polynomials/functions. Thank you :)